# Pull a dynamic prefix into the status (discord.py)

Tags: python, json, discord.py

I'm currently working on my Status, that contains *listening to .help*. Now I want, that the prefix changes, when I change the prefix dynamic with my command *.setprefix*  My code for this is:

```
@client.command()
async def setprefix(ctx, prefix):
    with open("./cogs/prefixes.json", "r") as f:
        prefixes = json.load(f)
    prefixes[str(ctx.guild.id)] = prefix
    with open("./cogs/prefixes.json", "w") as f:
        json.dump(prefixes, f, indent=4)

    await ctx.send(embed=discord.Embed(color=discord.Color.green(), title="Changed Prefix", description=f"Changed the prefix to **`{prefix}`**"))
```

How can I now set the prefix to readjust to the new state as well?
My Statusloop contains:

```
        while True:
            await self.client.change_presence(status=discord.Status.online, activity=discord.Activity(type=discord.ActivityType.watching, name="the developers"))
            await asyncio.sleep(10)
            await self.client.change_presence(status=discord.Status.online, activity=discord.Activity(type=discord.ActivityType.listening, name="to .help"))
            await asyncio.sleep(10)
```

To make the prefix dynamic, I uses this code:

```
def get_prefix(client, message):
    with open("./cogs/prefixes.json", "r") as f:
        prefixes = json.load(f)
    return prefixes[str(message.guild.id)]

client = commands.Bot(command_prefix=get_prefix)
```

Comment: Your code currently is not changing the prefix for the bot, only in the JSON file, is that what you intended?

Comment: Please [edit](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/66139336/edit) your question and add the code there, not in the comments

Comment: @ŁukaszKwieciński I added the code in the post

Answer (score 0):

What your code is doing, is changing the prefix for one guild. The status a bot displays, is the same on every server.

You can try the following, but I can't guarantee you, that it will work.

```py
with open('./cogs/prefixes.json', 'r') as f:
        prefixes = json.load(f)
    while True:
        await self.client.change_presence(status=discord.Status.online, activity=discord.Activity(type=discord.ActivityType.watching, name="the developers"))
        await asyncio.sleep(10)
        await self.client.change_presence(status=discord.Status.online, activity=discord.Activity(type=discord.ActivityType.listening, name="to prefixes[str(message.guild.id)]help")) # prefixes[str(message.guild.id)] is the prefix in your json file
        await asyncio.sleep(10)
```